# screenupdating = false, Excel UI will freeze

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I encountered a problem with 'screenupdating = false',
Excel will freeze.

```
public partial class Sheet1
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
    }

}
```

Have anyone encounter this problem?

Thanks.

Language - C#
OS - Windows 7 64bit
Tools - Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 + .Net Framework 4.6.2 + Office Excel 2010 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what its supposed to do. Excel is not freezed, in the background it still works e.g Calculations, Macro execution etc... Just the GUI stops refreshing, so that it can speed up the code execution.

MSDN :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx

You should always turnback screen updating to true, once code execution is done.

Similar property is `Application.DisplayAlerts`, if you set it to false then Excel stops showing default prompts such as confirmation for Sheet Delete.

Comment: teddy2:

I forget to check the VBA reference,

I will remember check next time.

Thank you for the advice.